# How to get xpath for the below img class having same values?

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation

How to get `xpath` for the below img class having same values?
Only aria described is unique, I want to click on the first image

```html
<img aria-label="More Detail" aria-describedby="card-heading_507" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0" src="/ui/services_co_myatt_overview/1.0.0/images/cbo_expand_icon.png" alt="More Detail" />

<img aria-label="More Detail" aria-describedby="card-heading_508" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0" src="/ui/services_co_myatt_overview/1.0.0/images/cbo_expand_icon.png" alt="More Detail" />

<img aria-label="More Detail" aria-describedby="card-heading_509" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0" src="/ui/services_co_myatt_overview/1.0.0/images/cbo_expand_icon.png" alt="More Detail" />
```

I tried the following but its not working:

```
//img[@src='/ui/services_co_myatt_overview/1.0.0/images/cbo_expand_icon.png'][1]
```

Comment: Update the question with some more outerHTML

Comment: try with (//img[@alt='More Detail'])[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
//img[@aria-describedby="card-heading_507"]
```

**EDIT:**

In order to check is the element really visible, enter `$x('//img[@aria-describedby="card-heading_507"]')` to console in DevTools and see if you can locate the element.

Comment: Error: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.all({By.xpath: //img[@aria-describedby='card-heading_507']})
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: Are you able to locate the element in the DevTools?

Comment: Enter `$x('//img[@aria-describedby="card-heading_507"]')` to console in DevTools and see if you can locate the element.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this.

```
//img[@aria-label="More Detail"][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only unique attribute is `aria-describedby`, you should use it!

```
imgPath = '//img[@aria-describedby="card-heading_507"]'
```

If you don't want to use hard-coded rather always catch the first `img` you can use `findElements` and locate the first element in the list...

```
lstOfImgs = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//img[@aria-label="More Detail"]'));
lstOfImgs[0]
```

Or you can refer to it in the Xpath see [example](http://xpather.com/KtreaYfK):

```
//img[@aria-label="More Detail"][1]
```